# Get column types of an SQL table with dplyr

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

Is there a `dplyr` (or other package) command for getting the column (field?) types of an SQL table? For example...

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

dat_sql <- src_sqlite("test.sqlite", create = TRUE)
copy_to(dat_sql, iris, name = "iris_df")

iris_tbl <- tbl(dat_sql, "iris_df")
iris_tbl
# Source:   query [?? x 5]
# Database: sqlite 3.8.6 [test.sqlite]
# 
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
# 8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# # ... with more rows
```

I'm interested in a command that would tell me that the first four columns are of type `dbl` and the last is a `chr` (or better yet, the R types `numeric` and `character`) *without actually* `collect`*ing the data in memory*. Since it is printed, there has to be a way to do this, right? I tried `str` to no avail:

```
str(iris_tbl)
# List of 2
#  $ src:List of 2
#   ..$ con :Formal class 'SQLiteConnection' [package "RSQLite"] with 5 slots
#   .. .. ..@ Id                 :<externalptr> 
#   .. .. ..@ dbname             : chr "test.sqlite"
#   .. .. ..@ loadable.extensions: logi TRUE
#   .. .. ..@ flags              : int 6
#   .. .. ..@ vfs                : chr ""
#   ..$ path: chr "test.sqlite"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "src_sqlite" "src_sql" "src"
#  $ ops:List of 3
#   ..$ src :List of 2
#   .. ..$ con :Formal class 'SQLiteConnection' [package "RSQLite"] with 5 slots
#   .. .. .. ..@ Id                 :<externalptr> 
#   .. .. .. ..@ dbname             : chr "test.sqlite"
#   .. .. .. ..@ loadable.extensions: logi TRUE
#   .. .. .. ..@ flags              : int 6
#   .. .. .. ..@ vfs                : chr ""
#   .. ..$ path: chr "test.sqlite"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "src_sqlite" "src_sql" "src"
#   ..$ x   :Classes 'ident', 'sql', 'character'  chr "iris_df"
#   ..$ vars: chr [1:5] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" ...
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_base_remote" "op_base" "op"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "tbl_sqlite" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
# NULL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When printing a preview of the remote table, it looks like dplyr does use `collect()` on the first few rows of the table. Because dplyr retrieves some sample data, you could do this as well.

Here, we make a query for the first few rows with `head()`, `collect()` the query results, and inspect the class of each column.

```
iris_tbl |> 
  head() |> 
  collect() |> 
  lapply(class) |> 
  unlist()
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#>    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"  "character"
```

(When used with a data-frame, `lapply()` does column-wise function application, so it applies `class()` to each column.)

To get the types names that dplyr uses, use `type_sum()`.

```
iris_tbl |> head() |> collect() |> lapply(type_sum) |> unlist()
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#>        "dbl"        "dbl"        "dbl"        "dbl"        "chr"
```

Comment: Feels unsatisfying, but can't deny that it works! Do you know if there is much overhead imposed on a `head` (or `tail`) statement for large databases? I often work with data that has on the order of several million rows.

Comment: Also, +1 for `type_sum` -- definitely was unaware of that command before!

Comment: Judging by the source code, it looks like for SQL dbs `head(..., n)` translates into a `select` statement with a `limit` of n rows.

Comment: Just a note: `type_sum()` can get you closer to the db types instead of R types, e.g. for postgres it will return `pq_json` where `typeof()` returns `character`

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `glimpse()`

> This is like a transposed version of print: columns run down the page,
>   and data runs across. This makes it possible to see every column in a
>   data frame. It's a little like str applied to a data frame but it
>   tries to show you as much data as possible. (And it always shows the
>   underlying data, **even when applied to a remote data source.**)

Which gives:

```
> glimpse(iris_tbl)
#Observations: NA
#Variables: 5
#$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0,...
#$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4,...
#$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5,...
#$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2,...
#$ Species      <chr> "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa",...
```

---

Should you want to get a vector you could do:

```
vapply(as.data.frame(head(iris_tbl)), typeof, character(1))
```

Which gives:

```
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#    "double"     "double"     "double"     "double"  "character"
```

Comment: Good command to know...but I still don't see how to actually access that "first column" containing the types without actually collecting a subset of the data.